# Array not capturing first user entry

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I am attempting to fill an array with floating point numbers using a method. Every time I run my program it does not capture the first number entered.

How can I correct my code so it captures the first user input?

Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    //Read user input into the array

    final int INITIAL_SIZE = 8;
    double[] inputs = new double[INITIAL_SIZE];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits for a course, Q to     quit:");
    double credits = in.nextDouble();

    int currentSize = 0;   

    while (in.hasNextDouble())
    {

        if (credits <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("All entries must be a positive number.");
        }

        else
        {    
            // Grow the array if it has been completely filled

            if (currentSize >= inputs.length)
            {
                 inputs = Arrays.copyOf(inputs, 2 * inputs.length);
            }
            inputs[currentSize] = in.nextDouble();
            currentSize++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputs));
 }
```

Comment: Why not use a `List`? `List<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>` and `inputs.add(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Prolem is

#### You did not store first user entry, so it's not showing to you

```
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits for a course, Q to     quit:");
 -->   double credits = in.nextDouble();
```

You have taken the value from user but did not stored it in `inputs`

If you want to take value of `credit` from user and want to store `credit` in `inputs` then you should do:

```
 double credits = in.nextDouble();
 inputs[0] = credits ;
    int currentSize = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in this line : `inputs[currentSize] = in.nextDouble();`
You are storing the first value in `credits` but not assigning it to `inputs` array.